# Javascript memory management: delete and splice

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management

When I remove items from an array in javascript using the splice method, an array of the removed items are returned.

```
var a = [{name:'object1'},{name:'object2'},{name:'object3'}];

// a.splice(0,2) -> [{name:'object1'},{name:'object2'}]
// Where do these guys live now? Are they really gone?
```

Do I then need to call 'delete' on those returned objects to make sure they are taken out of memory? Does the garbage collector just handle this? Can I trust that?

Answer (score 1):

The objects are 'gone' (from your perspective) and the GC will actually free the memory when it deems appropriate. JavaScript does not give you explicit control over garbage collection.

If you're concerned about performance, it's generally better (*after* profiling, of course) to focus on saving allocations rather than worrying about when exactly things will get GC'd, since that behavior will change depending on which JS engine you're on.